# How to set default Kendo control settings by JSON response

Tags: sql-server, json, kendo-ui, arcgis-server, kendo-combobox

I have 10 controls. One main dropdown that should decide what the other 9 controls are set to. These 9 controls are 3 rows of 3 dropdownboxes. Here's an example:

If dropdownMain has 'Address' selected then set dropdownbox1 to 'LastName'
set dropdownbox2 to '=' and set dropdownbox3 to a textbox.

set dropdownbox4 to 'FirstName' and set dropdownbox5 to '=' and set dropdownbox6 to a textbox.

set dropdownbox7 to 'City' and set dropdownbox8 to '=' and set dropdownbox9 to bind to a city json.

How do you tell the Kendo controls to respond to the first selection and then cascade? Or can you set a 'default configuration' by sending it via JSON? I'm sending from a ArcGIS Server SOE (server object extension).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add an event handler for the onchange event of the main drop down list and in that manually set what values the other drop down lists should display...?

Comment: That's the path I'm on... can you remind me how to get the 'text' value of a referenced dropdownlist in js? var columnName = cboSearchField2.text; isn't correct...

Answer (score 0):

OK this demonstrates a way to implement a solution to your problem as I understand it. I have only used 1 row of 3 drop downs and not 1 main drop down and then an additional 3 rows of drop downs, however, it is easily adaptable to suit your needs:

HTML (1 row of 3):

```
<select id="DropDownList1" name="DropDownList1"></select>
<select id="DropDownList2" name="DropDownList2"></select>
<span id="List">
    <select id="DropDownList3" name="DropDownList3"></select></span>
<span id="Text" style="display: none" >
    <input id="EnterText" class="k-textbox" /></span>
```

JS, Kendo UI, jQuery, jQuery UI:

```
var dataModel1 = [{ItemName: 'First Name', ItemId: 1},{ItemName: 'Middle Name', ItemId: 2},{ItemName: 'Last Name', ItemId: 3},{ItemName: 'Preferrred Name', ItemId: 4}];

var dataModel2 = [{ItemName: 'Equals', ItemId: 1},{ItemName: 'Contains', ItemId: 2},{ItemName: 'Starts With', ItemId: 3},{ItemName: 'Ends With', ItemId: 4}];

var dataModel3 = [{ItemName: 'John', ItemId: 1},{ItemName: 'Dave', ItemId: 2},{ItemName: 'Simon', ItemId: 3},{ItemName: 'Eric', ItemId: 4}];

$('#DropDownList1').kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: 'Select item...',
    dataTextField: 'ItemName',
    dataValueField: 'ItemId',
    change: function(e) {
        var that = this, ddlQuery = $('#DropDownList2').data('kendoDropDownList');

        if(ddlQuery !== undefined) {
            switch(that.value()) {
                case '1':
                    ddlQuery.value('2');
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    },
    dataSource: {
        data: dataModel1,
        schema: {
            data: function(response) { return response || {}; }
        }
    }
});

$('#DropDownList2').kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: 'Select item...',
    dataTextField: 'ItemName',
    dataValueField: 'ItemId',
    change: function(e) {
         var that = this, ddlQuery = $('#DropDownList3').data('kendoDropDownList');
        if(ddlQuery !== undefined) {
        switch(that.value()) {
            case '1':
                 $('#List').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                     $('#Text').fadeIn();
                });
                break;
            default:
                $('#Text').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                     $('#List').fadeIn();
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    dataSource: {
        data: dataModel2,
        schema: {
            data: function(response) { return response || {}; }
        }
    }
});

$('#DropDownList3').kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: 'Select item...',
    dataTextField: 'ItemName',
    dataValueField: 'ItemId',
    change: function(e) {

    },
    dataSource: {
        data: dataModel3,
        schema: {
            data: function(response) { return response || {}; }
        }
    }
});
```

The jsFiddle for this can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8PW98/17/

I hope this helps...

Comment: this looks great. I will likely adapt what I've come with to function a bit more like this. I am realizing that by not having any ID fields in my data it's really a struggle. I'm using a view from SQL with no ID field...